# Fluid and Flexible Image Slideshow with jQuery

Tags: jquery, slideshow, fluid

Does anyone know if there is a jquery plugin for a "responsive" image slideshow?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Check out this [Responsive jQuery Slideshow](http://blog.kiskolabs.com/post/5602656614/responsive-jquery-slideshow) article.

Comment: That's exactly what I was after. Cheers Sayem!

Answer (score 0):

There is this one:

http://www.pixedelic.com/plugins/camera/

It's responsive and with tons of features. The only warning about it, is that you have to be very careful whenever modifying the css and also make sure to test it on browsers such as IE7 and IE8, I'm not 100% positive that this slideshow works on those browsers. You are welcome to give it a try, though.

Comment: It does work in IE8.  Not perfectly in IE7 (could with some css tweaks).  This was not difficult to test - you should do so next time....